# A Chrome extension to clean and deobfuscate long referral URL links?

Tags: chrome

I am looking for a Chrome extension that automatically transforms long and obfuscated URLs into the real URLs.

**Example how it is at the moment:**

```
https://nylas.com/blog/nylas-pro/?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Nylas%20Pro%20Announcement&utm_content=Nylas%20Pro%20Announcement+CID_ac818d46fdab699a20daff65deef674d&utm_source=Campaign%20Monitor&utm_term=Read%20More
```

[image]

**Example how I want it to be:**

```
https://nylas.com/blog/nylas-pro
```

Comment: How would it know what's obfuscated URL and what's not?

Comment: Dear @Tom, that's a good question...maybe based on the length and number of `?` used?

Comment: Ya, that would be nice especially, for example, google search result links. IDK any personally but maybe someone else does

Comment: where would the transformed URL be shown?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ ideally in the URL bar. If impossible, it would be copied to the clipboard after clicking on the extension icon in the toolbar.

Comment: would you be willing to use a userscript? It would have a shortcut that you press which would prompt you to ctrl+c the transformed URL...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ yes, absolutely! I would love to try it. :-)

Comment: That is **not** an "obfuscated URL", it is a URL with some Google Analytics parameters added in the query string (`utm_source` and so on). These can be removed because the website does not change the content of the page, but what would you do if the last parameter was something like `productId=3`? There is no way a tool can automatically detect "useless" and "necessary" parameters automatically. One needs to understand the structure of the CMS the site is using. If you are looking for a tool that strips a query string regardless of its importance, than it needs to be stated clearly. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a quick userscript to do this.

When you press Ctrl + Shift + U (if you want a different shortcut, please comment and I'll change it for you :), you'll get a prompt to copy a cleaned-up version of the URL:

[image]

This will work in both Firefox and Chrome.

If you're using Firefox, you'll need to install the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-gb/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) extension first.

If you're using Chrome, you'll need to install the [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) extension first.

Then, just [click this link](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Answers_scripts/raw/master/UrlDeobfuscator.user.js) to install it -- Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey will detect it's a userscript and ask you to install it.

---

The code, if you're interested :)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         URL deobfuscater
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/
// @version      1.0
// @description  A userscript that lets you quickly copy a cleaned-up version of the current URL
// @author       ᔕᖺᘎᕊ (http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/)
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    document.onkeyup = function(e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && (e.keyCode == 117 || e.keyCode == 85)) {
            window.prompt('Press Ctrl+C/Ctrl+X', location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + location.pathname);
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: This is a great first step, thank you! Where can I report bugs?

Comment: @orschiro either here as a comment, or as an issue at https://github.com/shu8/SE-Answers_scripts/, where this file is saved :)